# Does pointwise convergence imply norm convergence in a reproducing kernel hilbert space if the norm has limit?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a real reproducing kernel Hilbert space, which can thus be seen as a space of real valued functions defined on some domain $\Omega$.  It is known that, if a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of functions of $H$ converges to a certain function $f$ in the norm of the Hilbert space, then $f_n$ converges to $f$ also pointwise.  I'd like to know if the inverse holds in a particular case.  Explicitly:

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions of $H$ such that for all $x\in \Omega$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)
$$
for some function $f\in H$.  Suppose moreover that we know that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \Vert f - f_n\Vert_H
$$
exists.  Then is this last limit equal to zero?

Comment: Let $\phi \in C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ be a bump function ($\phi \ge 0; \forall |x|\ge 1, \phi(x) = 0; \phi(0) = 1$) and consider $f_n(t) = \phi(t - n)$.