# Proving that convergence in RKHS implies pointwise convergence without using reproducing property

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, pointwise-convergence, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{K})$ be a reproducing kernel Hilbert space and denote $\mathcal{K}_x := \mathcal{K}(x, \cdot)$.
Is there a simple way to prove $f_n \to_\mathcal{H} f$ (shorthand for $\|f_n - f\|_\mathcal{H} \to 0$) implies $f_n \to f$ pointwise without having to invoke the reproducing property $\langle g, \mathcal{K}_x \rangle_\mathcal{H} = g(x)$?

I'm likely misunderstanding something, but it appears to me that this result is needed to prove the reproducing property itself for functions not in $\mathcal{S} := \text{span}\{\mathcal{K}_x | x \in \mathcal{X}\}$ but in its completion when constructing the RKHS $\mathcal{H}$.
It is easy to see that any function in $\mathcal{S}$ satisfies the reproducing property.
For $f \in \mathcal{H} \setminus \mathcal{S}$, by definition we can always find a sequence $f_n$ in $\mathcal{S}$ such that $f_n \to_\mathcal{H} f$. Then,

\begin{align*}
\langle f, \mathcal{K}_x \rangle_\mathcal{H}
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle f_n, \mathcal{K}_x \rangle_\mathcal{H}
\quad \text{since } \langle \cdot, \mathcal{K}_x \rangle_\mathcal{H} \text{ is continuous w.r.t } \| \cdot \|_\mathcal{H} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)
\quad \text{by the reproducing property for functions in } \mathcal{S} \\
&= f(x)
\quad \text{assuming we can use the fact that } f_n \to_\mathcal{H} f \text{ implies } f_n \to f.
\end{align*}

**Edit**:
To be clear, I'm following the proof of Theorem 12.11 from [Wainwright's High-dimensional statistics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E), which states that

> For any positive semidefinite kernel $\mathcal{K}$, there is a unique Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathbb{R}^\mathcal{X}$ in which the kernel satisfies the reproducing property:
> $$\langle f, \mathcal{K}_x \rangle_\mathcal{H} = f(x) \quad \forall f \in \mathcal{H}.$$
> $\mathcal{H}$ is known as the RKHS associated with $\mathcal{K}$.

Therefore, instead of defining the RKHS to be a space of bounded evaluation functionals (this appears as a theorem in the book), the goal is to construct the RKHS by completing the span of $\{\mathcal{K}_x\}_{x \in \mathcal{X}}$ and show that it satisfies all the required properties.

Comment: Isn't this guaranteed by the definition of RKHS? i.e., the functional $f \mapsto f(x)$ is linear and continous.

Comment: @daw Thanks for the comment! Can you clarify what this entails? I know this can be used in conjunction with the reproducing property to prove that RKHS convergence implies pointwise convergence, but this creates a tautology if I then want to apply this result to prove the reproducing property.

Comment: The definition of RKHS on wikipedia is that the evaluation functionals $f\mapsto f(x)$ are continuous wrt to the RKHS-norm. Then $f_n \to f$ in $H$ implies $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @daw Ah I realize where the confusion is - I'm starting from a different definition of RKHS. Instead of defining it to be the space of continuous/bounded evaluation functionals, the book I'm following defines it to be the unique Hilbert space that satisfies the reproducing property. I'll update the post to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @daw, for a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ to become a RKHS the evaluation functionals $L_{x}​(f):=f(x)$ must be continuous, which is equivalent to being bounded. Thus for every $x$ there is a $M_{x}$ with $L_{x}(f)=f(x)\leq M_{x} \| f \|_{\mathcal{H}}$.

It follows that $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ implies the pointwise convergence. Pick an arbitrary $x$ then
$$
|f(x)-f_{n}(x)|=|(f-f_{n})(x)|=|L_{x}(f-f_{n})| \leq M_{x}\|f-f_{n}\|
$$
and since $\|f_{n} - f\| \rightarrow 0$ we see that $f_{n}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know of this proof but wasn't able to apply it since the book I'm following starts from a different definition (see edit). The second equality of your equation is where I got stumped - when written as an inner product it is the reproducing property, which is exactly what I was trying to prove.

Comment: I think in some way or another you will need to use this property since this is what distinguishes a RKHS from a Hilbert space. And in a Hilbert space your implication does not hold as can be seen f.e. by considering $L^{2}$.

Comment: What I gathered from the book is that the property should arise naturally from a given positive semidefinite kernel. 
This video showcases a similar proof (theorem at 4:00):
http://y2u.be/EoM_DF3VAO8
However, it also skimmed over the reproducing property part for functions in the completion (28:54).

Comment: I think what you are looking for is he [Moore-Aronszajn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Moore%E2%80%93Aronszajn_theorem). As you can see, the reproducing property arises from the definition of the inner product on $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the theorem I'm looking for. 
My original question boils down to justifying taking the infinite sum out of the inner product, which I assume will be a result of some convergence theorem (getting too rusty on these...)
Can you update your answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @Sleeper If that's your question, this follows from the continuity of the inner product.

Comment: Take a convergent series $x_{n}$ with limit $x$ and $y$, then (by Cauchy-Schwarz) $|\langle x-x_{n}, y \rangle | \leq \|x-x_{n}\| \|y\|$. Since $\|x-x_{n}\| \rightarrow 0$ the continuity in the first argument follows.

Comment: I know the inner product is continuous with respect to its induced norm, however the convergence in this case is pointwise rather than with respect to the Hilbert space norm?

Comment: @Sleeper Taking the sum out of the inner product is a consequence of the continuity. Simply write $_:=\sum_{}^{n}x_{i}$, then $\langle \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_{i},y\rangle=\langle \lim_{n \to \infty}s_{n}, y \rangle=\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle s_{n}, y \rangle=\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}, y \rangle$.

Comment: My main issue with this argument is that while $\| s_n - s \|_\mathcal{H} \to 0$ means $\langle s, y \rangle = \langle \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n, y \rangle_\mathcal{H} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle s_n, y \rangle$, whether the statement still holds when instead $s_n \to s$ pointwise. 
This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996937/does-pointwise-convergence-imply-norm-convergence-in-a-reproducing-kernel-hilber) seems to contain a potential counterexample.